# tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_channel_shift() does not work with tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, preprocessor

I am using TensorFlow 2.5, the problem is when I load images using `image_dataset_from_directory()` or with `tensor_slices`, when I want to apply augmentation with `.map()` function on dataset, when I want to use `random_channel_shift`, it raises the following error:
Tensor object has no attribute "`ndim`".

below is my sample code:

```
def augment(image, label):
  image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_channel_shift(image, 100.0)

    # return the image and the label
  return (image, label)

def prepare(ds):
  ds = ds.map(augment, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

  # Use buffered prefecting on all datasets
  return ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

traindata_tfds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
path_train, labels='inferred', label_mode='categorical',
class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=Batch_size, image_size=(256,
256), shuffle=True, seed=None, validation_split=None, subset=None,
interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False, smart_resize=True)

train_ds = prepare(traindata_tfds)
```

Same problem when using tensor_slices instead of image_dataset_from_directory.

Comment: Yes, for god knows what reason, all these functions in `keras.preprocessing` work on _numpy arrays_ only...

Comment: exactly, but in the documents have written you can pass tensor to it.

Comment: Right, but for example the function you mention says that it returns a "numpy image tensor". They may simply be referring to numpy arrays as tensors. It should actually work with `tf.Tensor` as well with eager execution, but unfortunately the `tf.data` ops always build a graph (they are not eager). If you check [the source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/affine_transformations.py#L183-L195) you will see that these functions use numpy.

Comment: @xdurch0 exactly, what can i do?
i want to train a very deep and heavy model on a large dataset and i need most efficient and rapid data loader.